# Can a single adjective be an appositive for the clause?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> He made no comment and there was a long and unhappy pause during which
> the cab leapt forward a foot or so, only to pause and pant again,
> **frustrated**.

I thought 'frustrated' explained the atmosphere of the whole part of the sentence before it. Then, can I assume it is a kind of appositive?

Comment: I'd say ***frustrated*** adverbially modifies preceding ***pause and pant*** - exactly the same as ***bemused*** modifies the preceding verb (phrase) in, say, [*At one point he **halted, bemused.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22point+he+halted+bemused%22)

Comment: You have the cab as frustrated there. Not the guy. It would have to be: Frustrated, **he made no comment etc.** Furthermore, cabs don't pause and pant, which is another problem with the sentence...

Comment: No: appositives are always noun phrases. As written, it implies that it was the cab that was frustrated. Is this the intended meaning?

Answer (score 2):

There are several definitions of "appositive" out there, but what they have in common is that the two things in apposition stand in the same syntactic relationship to the rest of the sentence and are semantically co-referential.

**frustrated** fails both of those tests.

A constituent that "explains" or "sums up" or expresses an outcome or result, isn't an instance of apposition:

> He rolled down the hill hitting his head on rocks along the way, *dazed and bruised*.

Descriptors  are not appositives of the nouns they describe as they do not stand in the same syntactic relationship, as constituents, to the rest of the sentence. If, for example, the first constituent is the subject of the verb, then the appositive must be subject of the verb.

With apposition, two constituents refer to the same thing and have the same grammatical relationship to the rest of the sentence:

> Greed, the deadliest of the deadly sins, was his topic.
>
> The preacher spoke of Greed, the deadliest of the deadly sins.

Some definitions will admit parallel verb phrases as appositive:

> He was *living the life, firing on all cylinders*, until Fate in the form of Delphine Dubonnet waltzed into his life.

Here is a good definition  of **appositive** from Merriam-Webster:

> a pair or occasionally a series of usually adjacent words, phrases, or clauses (especially nouns or noun equivalents) that have the same referent *and that stand in the same syntactical relation to the rest of the sentence* (such as the poet and Burns in "a biography of the poet Burns") : a pair or series of words, phrases, or clauses standing in grammatical apposition
> [ my emphasis ]

Comment: Of course, an appositive is a kind of restatement and as such cannot be just a past participle as adjective.

Comment: @Lambie Exactly, unless there are two such adjectives or adjective phrases, one after the other, and then they could be said to stand in apposition:  "He took one sip of the poison and fell over backwards, *dead as a doornail, silent as snow*."

Comment: Only NPs can be appositives. Appositives, by definition, are those NPs that when substituted for the matrix NP systematically yield a clause which is an entailment of the original.

Comment: @BillJ: That's the CGEL definition?   M-W casts a wider net.

Comment: Don't use dictionaries for grammar -- only for spellings and meanings. In any case M-W is a dinosaur of a dictionary; probably the worst on the market.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible reading seems to be by taking *frustrated* as modifying *the cab*. It is then a bit of a metaphor, a personification or similar.

> frustrated, the cab leapt forward a foot or so, only to pause and pant again

The late position of the modifier, combined with the fact that we don't generally think of cabs are being frustrated, makes the sentence a bit awkward. But I'd say it still works.

Comment: They are not grammatically the same class of constituent (Noun/NounPhrase, for example) and so **frustrated** would not be considered apposition under any definition of the term.  **Frustrated** might be considered to apply to "cab", but it isn't a *substitute* for "cab".

Comment: @TimRonadifferentdevice: I have also seen the term *appositive* used with adjectivals, if they are clearly placed in a different position. But I agree with you that *modifying* is perhaps the clearest, least controversial term, I've changed it.

Comment: Removed the downvote.  You might say that the italicized phrases in this sentence are apposite:  ""He was *as happy as a lark, as content as a clam*" but neither of them is apposite the subject.

Comment: Frustrated, he leapt out of the cab ont the sidewalk. But I don't think a cab can be frustrated....Anyway, a single adjective cannot be appositive which is a restatement of something.

Comment: This answer is (I think) the more useful one, since the issue of categorizing the construction is moot if the sentence doesn't make any sense.